# Problem with i:0#.w| before domain name

Tags: login, domain

I have this code:

```
SPWeb theSite = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
SPUser theUser = theSite.CurrentUser;
string strUserName = theUser.LoginName.ToLower();
```

How to remove **i:0#.w|** in Shareoint 2013. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
SPWeb theSite = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
SPUser theUser = theSite.CurrentUser;
string strUserName = theUser.LoginName.ToLower();
string strUserName = strUserName.IndexOf('|') > -1 ? strUserName.Split('|')[1] : strUserName
```